# Bind different property than what is shown in the html component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

Consider I have a list of objects like -

```
var configs = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "config1"
},
 {
    id: "2",
    name: "config2"
 }
];
```

I use the following to search through the config list and bind the selected config to another variable called `changed_config`.

```
<table style="width:900px;">
<tr>
   <th style="width:500px; margin:50px">Config Name</th>
   <th style="width:150px;">Config Value</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="changed_config in changed_configs">
   <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="changed_config.id" list="names">
      <datalist id="names">
         <option ng-repeat="option in configs | filter:search | limitTo:30" ng-value="option.name"> {{option.name}}
         </option>
      </datalist>
   <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="changed_config.value">
   </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" id="add-reward-grp-btn" ng-click="addConfig()"
       class="btn btn-primary">Add Config                 
  </button>
</div>
```

Controller Code(Not complete code, just relevant snippets):

```
var app = angular.module("drs_scheduler_app", []);
app.controller("CreateSchedulerJob", function ($scope, $http) {
          $scope.changed_configs = []; 
          $scope.configs = [{
                   id: "1",
                   name: "config1"
                   },
                   {
                   id: "2",
                   name: "config2"
                   }
          ];

        $scope.addConfig = function () {
          var config = {
              "id": "",
              "value": ""
          };
          $scope.changed_configs.push(config);
          console.log(config);
          console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.changed_configs));
        }
}
```

Currently the code displays and binds the `name` of the selected config to the `changed_config` variable. But I need the `id` to be bound to the `changed_config` variable and the `name` to be displayed in the html.

If I change the `<option>` to use id, then `id` will be displayed.

How do I bind one property to a variable but show another in the html??

Comment: change `ng-value="option.name"` to `ng-value="option.id"`

Comment: I think i'm missing something here. Why can't you use ng-value="option.id" ?

Comment: But that will then display the `id` in the input field. I need to show the `name` in the field but bind the `id` to the variable

Comment: Then you need to set ng-value="option" and do whatever with it

Comment: which input field you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you needed,

**Procedure:**

> 1. When an `option` is `selected` from `datalist` I m checking for **that
>      change**
> 2. That **change is observed through `input`** on which `datalist` is added
> 3. On that `input change` i,e **when option is selected** I m assigning that
>      id to id key of respective `changed_config`
> 4. That is inturn displayed in second textbox
> 5. It works for `dynamic`

```js
// Code goes here

function cntryController($scope) {
  
  
  $scope.LoadSessionData=function(val)
  {
    
     console.log(val);
    
   
    
  };
  
      $scope.changed_configs = []; 
          $scope.configs = [{
                   id: "1",
                   name: "config1"
                   },
                   {
                   id: "2",
                   name: "config2"
                   }
          ];

        $scope.addConfig = function () {
          var config = {
              "id": "",
              "value": ""
          };
          $scope.changed_configs.push(config);
          console.log(config);
          console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.changed_configs));
        }
  
    
  $scope.test = function(data, index){
    console.log(data)
    var newArray = $scope.configs.filter(function (config) {
  return config.name == data;
});
    console.log(newArray)
    if(newArray.length){
      var new_changed_config = $scope.changed_configs[index];
      new_changed_config.id = newArray[0].id;
    }
  }
  
  
  
  
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="" ng-controller="cntryController">


    <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <th>Config Name</th>
            <th>Config Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="changed_config in changed_configs">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="changed_config.name" list="names" ng-change="test(changed_config.name, $index)">                
                <datalist id="names">
                    <option ng-repeat="option in configs | filter:search | limitTo:30" value={{option.name}}>{{option.name}}
                    </option>
                </datalist>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="changed_config.id"/>
            </td>
        
        </tr>
        

    </table>
    <div class="row">
            <button type="button" id="add-reward-grp-btn" ng-click="addConfig()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Config</button>
        </div>

</div>

</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fmk5l2Lijp9TZDhma94L?p=preview)

Comment: also, where you are initializing `changed_config`

Comment: I tried that too. If I bind the object, the input field which is above the `<datalist>` displays `[object Object]` and also binds the same.

Comment: `changed_config` is initialised in the controller

Comment: I've edited the question to include the controller code

Comment: what is `changed_reward_configs` and you used `changed_config` in html, but it is not there in controller

Comment: See now. I changed the variable name for the question. It was a typo in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171214/discussion-between-sravan-and-leoorion).

Comment: @leoOrion, updated answer and added DEMO, please check

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think of using ng-change.